# Pay later option on 4.7.2 using Stripe doesn't work - throwing error

Tags: upgrade, payment-processor, 4.7, stripe

Have events set up - working fine in 4.6.x updated to 4.7,2

Getting the following error - when hitting continue on event registration 
Payment Error Response:
Error: The card object must have a value for 'number'.

Thoughts - Suggestions ?

Drupal 7.4.3

Comment: Can this be replicated on the demo site?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the Stripe payment processor.

The javascript file in stripe needs to be updated because the name of the payment processor changed in 4.7 from "payment_processor" to "payement_processor_id".

The [Stripe Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/stripe-payment-processor) does not yet have a 4.7 branch to push these changes to.

Answer (score 0):

I did test the same against http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

It went alright. But, with an higher version of CiviCRM 4.7.4
So, Please try to upgrade to Civicrm 4.7.4 version and give a test

Also for you reference please try the below link - which works fine 
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=7&noFullMsg=true